# what will be the answer of this pointer based code and why?

Tags: c

This is the code.Can someone explain its output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int i;
    double a=5.2;
    char*ptr;
    ptr=(char*)&a;
    for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
    printf("%d",*ptr++);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Output? What is it's output?

Comment: Casting from address of double to char pointer is basically undefined behavior. Depending on platform, compiler and changes of the weather, there is no way telling what it would be.

Comment: Unless you know the IEEE 754 format by heart, the output is meaningless. Read more about the [double-precision floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: It will be *Undefined Behavior* for violating [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) (even though the technical cast to `char` is legal) your subsequent use of `ptr` with the `"%d"` format specifier in `printf("%d",*ptr++);` is not.

Comment: Even if you do know the IEEE 754 format, and even if the implementation uses IEEE 754 format, the output can still vary between implementations due to [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: @David, can you please clarify (in simple words) why printing bytes of double or integer type is UB?

Comment: Sure [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) `"If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Isn't UB invoked here `ptr=(char*)&a`? Also, `*ptr++` is a `char` and I'm pretty sure that it can be used with `%d`. So not sure about the quote you linked

Comment: @Diodacus, I doubt that casting pointers from any type to any other type is undefined behaviour. Result maybe confusing though.

Comment: Technically No because `ptr` is a `char type` see [C11 Standard - 6.5 Expressions(p7) (last bullet)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7) so the cast to `char*` doesn't run afoul of the scrict aliasing rule. This is one of the "clear-as-mud" sections of the standard, but it was written to keep someone from trying to reference a `double` as an `int` after casting to an intervening `char*` or `void*` `:)` The memory holding `a` has a *declared type* of `double`. So while integer promotion will handle printing a `char` as `int`, the value at the referenced location is `double`.

Comment: In fact, what will happen in this case is you will attempt to interpret the *sign-bit* (1-bit) the biased exponent (11-bits) and the first 20-bits of the normalized mantissa for the IEEE-754 Double-Precision Floating Point representation of `5.2`. Which would be `01000000000101001100110011001100` or the integer equivalent `1075104972`. I'm not saying the compiler won't do it, I'm saying doing it in the way you are doing it violates the spirit of the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I don't see UB — strict aliasing is not a problem when using a `char *` to access data.  Since the `char` from `*ptr++` will be promoted to `int` in the `printf()`, there is no UB in the printing.  It won't be easy to interpret the printed values — it depends on whether the computer is big-endian or little-endian, and on whether plain `char` is a signed or unsigned type.  But I'm reasonably sure there isn't UB involved.

Comment: I agree technically as stated in my comment that the intervening cast to `char*` isn't UB. The problem I see is the compiler would complain with `int*ptr;` and `ptr=(int*)&a;` before calling `printf("%d",*ptr++);`. Avoiding application of the rule by going to `char` to use as `int` seems no different than casting to `(void*)` to accomplish the same. The end result is `printf("%d",*ptr++);` accesses the address where a `double` is stored. So while I agree the intervening cast makes the compiler happy, it's one of the quirks with 6.5 (6/7) that sure does violate the spirit of the rule.

Comment: I guess the preferred approach would be to take the pointer out of it completely and simply use a `union`, e.g. `union { double a; char b[sizeof (double)];} dbl2c = { .a = 5.2 };` then `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) printf (" %d", dbl2c.b[i]);` It eliminates the pointer issue completely.

Answer (score 1):

The `double` `5.2`'s memory layout is `01000000 00010100 11001100 11001100
11001100 11001100 11001100 11001101`. You can check it [here](https://www.binaryconvert.com)

Because your standard PC is little endian, the last byte comes first.

So, the first byte `11001101` will be promoted to `int` and printed. It is `-51`.
The second byte `11001100` will be printed as `-52`.
third `-52`
...`-52`
`-52`
`-52`
`20`
`64`

So, with no space in between the output is `-51-52-52-52-52-522064`.

https://ideone.com/AQM5iW

This holds only for little endian machines, signed `char` and IEEE-754 doubles. For big endian machines the output would be `6420-52-52-52-52-52-51`. If your `char` is unsigned the `-51` will be `205` and the `-52` will be `204`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin was a typo, thanks.

Comment: We all knew what you meant `:)`